# Forum based on xPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, hcl

Unfortunately I have a problem with an Forum Based on Domino FP9 Server. Several pages are created with the framework/language xpages. I have created a group and also a category. But the user is unable to get access the content.

My question is: How I can implement the right to an Group inside HCL Admin or Designer to read content on an Page?

Kind Regards

Okan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access is granted via the Access Control List of the application.  In HCL Notes Administrator, find the application on the Files Tab.  Right-click and choose Access Control > Manage.  IMPORTANT - DO NOT choose Manage Directory ACL in error.

In the dialog that opens up, you should be able to add groups/individuals with appropriate levels of access.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the problem is.... i.e. what it has to do with HCL Admin or Designer to do?

However, security in an XPage is exactly the same as with everything else Notes/Domino - so you can use that knowledge to control access rights.

A group in reality works like a single person in terms of access. So you can use it in the ACL of a database and/or in Readers/Authors fields (to control access to specific documents).

If you want to control *functions* or *layout* inside your application then I would suggest using ***Roles*** as these give an extra abstraction layer and are way easier to use in e.g. hide-when formulas inside your code. And then you just assign the role to a group or person in the ACL of the database.

Remember to set the right *type* of the entry in the ACL (e.g. *Persons* for a group that contain persons) - otherwise you can have issues where the server will not grant the expected access ;-)